# Batch script command only works once, the loop does not work

Tags: batch-file

I am making a simple script for a network where ever a homefolder is created for every user. Making the users + putting them in the correct group works perfectly but as soon as I add the homefolder part it only executes once.
This script is called 9 times in another script but it only works once.

```
rem ****** %1 username
rem ****** %2 password
rem ****** %3 group



net user %1 %2 /ADD 
net user %1 /logonpasswordchg:no 
net user %1 /active:yes 
net user %1 /expires:NEVER 
net user %1 /times:M-F,8-18
net user %1 /passwordchg:no

net group %3 %1 /add


C:
cd \School\Homefolders\Leerlingen
md %1
echo Y| cacls C:\School\Homefolders\Leerlingen\%1 /G %1:C administrators:F
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..
C:
```

Comment: Which HomeFolders line is it? There are 2...

Comment: The 2nd line is for the permissions on the homefolder?

Comment: Yeah, but you didn't specify the line where it was causing problems. The 1st line I presume then?

Comment: That is the problem i don't know what is causing it not to redo the code. The other script with the call works, I have tested that multiple times. So even with "echo Y| cacls C:\School\Homefolders\Leerlingen\%1 /G %1:C administrators:F" left out the script does exactly the same. It creates a folder 1 time and then it just stops.

Comment: Ok. If the problem is with the `cd` line it could be it's not actually changing to the right drive. The line that says `C:` won't actually do anything, try using `cd /d C:` instead and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a similar example and had the same problem caused by changing the directories. You also have an extra "cd .." statement. Try just using the following:

```
md C:\School\Homefolders\Leerlingen\%1
echo Y| cacls C:\School\Homefolders\Leerlingen\%1 /G %1:C administrators:F
```

I'm also assuming as it otherwise gets called multiple times that you've remembered to use a call statement in the batch file that calls that one.